# Jenkins access msbuild file in github probject

Tags: git, github, jenkins, msbuild

### My current situtation

I learning how to write Unit Tests with NUnit 3.4. The whole time I had like 3 Steps.

**1.)** I write my C#-Project with unit tests

**2.)** In the same folder where my Solution is, I have a [**msbuild-file**](http://pastebin.com/1q6aNCcx) which build my project and creates stuff like:

- Console-Report.xml
- MyProject.dll
- MyProject.pdb
- MyProject_Test.dll
- MyProject_Test.pdb
- nunit.framework.dll
- nunit.framewirk.xml

**3.)** I use Jenkins (nunit- und msbuildPlugins are installed): Every time I press "Build now" it calls my msbuild-file in the project folder:

[image]

So far, so good.

### What I want

Now I want Jenkins to build every time I change and update my code and I read that there are many ways to do that. I want to try it with Github.

**1.)** I created a new repository "CannonAttack" and imported my project "MyCannonAttack"

**2.)** I connected more or less Github with Jenkins via this [article](http://automatetheplanet.com/integrate-jenkins-github/) successfully. See here:
[image]

But now I need to run my msbuild-file, which is on github. How can I call/access it? This is my [github-project](https://github.com/arsi0001/CannonAttack). In the next folder you can finde the msbuild-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your MSBuild Build File value to: `${WORKSPACE}\CannonAttack\MyCannonAttack\TestK.msbuild`

Or possibly `${WORKSPACE}\MyCannonAttack\TestK.msbuild`You can click on "Workspace" on the left of the job page to see exactly where it is... In case I'm off by one folder in my suggestion. But ${WORKSPACE} is an environment variable that allows you to access the paths that you pull to with source control.

Comment: oh ok, thanks!! :) I will try tomorrow :) I guess it will work with your answer!